# Simple Eigenvalue Idea

Tags: r, matrix, eigenvalue

I have a vector `Nx1` with numbers that I want to be the eigenvalues of a matrix X which I am attempting to construct. Essentially, I want to take my `Nx1` matrix and list the `ith` entry of this vector on the `ith` diagonal of this matrix. I have tried various matrix multiplications, but nothing seems to be working. Can someone help me out?

Cheers.

Note that I am attempting to do this in R.

Comment: It would be better if you provide code for your best attempt, and the reason why is not working. That will help narrow down your question. Thanks.

Comment: When you say vector you are talking of a matrix row? Or a real vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk of code works for vectors

```
eigenvalues <- 1:10
matrix <- diag(eigenvalues)
```

This works for a matrix

```
eigenvalues <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 1)
matrix <- diag(eigenvalues[, 1])
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.